# run project failed cause deploy error in visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-emulator

**hi everyone.**

when i debug windows phone project in visual studio got an error in deploy app on emulator:
*"Error : DEP6100 : The following unexpected error occurred during boostrapping stage 'Downloading package '7123B57E-F819-4B1E-8EE2-677E10756394'': 
FileNotFoundException - The system cannot find the file specified."**

the phone emulator run clearly but when VS want to deploy it on emulator i got this error, i think it's occur because of firewall or antivirus or maybe update windows is necessary. so i do all thing for fix this problem but it doesn't work(i reinstall VS).

my system:
Win 8.1 64bit pro
Visual studio update 4.

please help me to fix that.

cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the language in the below setting,  is other than English, can you please try changing it to English and let us know if it works?
Options -> International Settings -> Language

Answer (score 0):

everything is ok and my language set to English by default.